# Renaming css file in production server

Tags: css

I am just curious why some website rename their css file name to a very long name. For example, I inspect the source code of the link: https://kippt.com/

and their css filename is very long. As my understanding, the company is using twitter bootstrap as their web UI framework.

I am just wondering is there a benefit to rename the css file? If it does, can anyone tell me what's the proper way to do that?

Sorry for this dumb question. I am very new to web development and would like to know more about this.

Thanks.

Comment: Renaming the css file after changes forces the browser to not use a cached version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sometimes the CSS file is dynamically generated and then that name is used (inserted) to the page. was this a "portal" page or template site?

Comment: The CSS file name isn't that long in the site  in your link its actually "97014f308af8.css" the rest of it is the PATH or the LOCATION in the folders on the server

Comment: Zaf, you are right but just wonder why they name looks like a random name?

Silvertiger, can you tell me more about what is a portal page/template stie?

Comment: a portal site is usually a site that is customizable for either an individual company, specific user, or perhaps bought from a "template" site and modified to suit the purchaser.  These do not always (and typically do not) use a dynamic file name, but when I have seena dynamic css file name it is because the styles are dependant upon login name, permissions, or folder location. Once these are determined the CSS file can be scripted with another language (php, asp, etc) to write the file to the server Just before the page is built, and given a dynamic name.

Comment: Dynamically generating a CSS file is okay, but I cannot see any benefit to using a unique name each time. I can only imagine that having a file name like 97014f308af8.css is doing exactly that. If your CSS is large, and doesn't change often, then all you are doing is forcing your viewer to download a giant file every time they request your page rather than take advantage of caching.

Comment: It is possible that this is done to avoid caching the template file (i.e. when one user logs in it has his style, but another user gets another style) if they keep overwriting the same file the page willlook wrong for some people, hence the random name (maybe, as this is all hypothetical)

Comment: @Silvertiger, as long as that file name doesn't change for the user, that's probably okay. If it changes every request, I can't think of a poorer design.

Comment: agreed .. like I said .. this is one of the few instances where a dynamic file would be used.  other than that .. perhaps the user that made the code is eccentric and likes long file names... but in all truth a css file named "97014f308af8.css" feels auto generated.

Comment: also .. it may not be that it changes every time the user logs in, it may only change per user, or when the settings that control the dynamic css are adjustd, merely to prevent caching.